# Custom validators/filters in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

How do I make custom validators/filter classes in Zend Framework?

I have done by changes in library but I don't want to do changes in core library files.

Is there any way to do this without changing library files?

Comment: Why haven't you read the documentation? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.writing_filters.html

Comment: gone through it but  not getting exactly where to put files

Comment: put them wherever you want. Zend doesn't require any specific location. You have `libary/Zend` directory? If so - create `library/My` one, if not - just create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this without changing library files?

Sure, just place your filter into a file of it's own and make it accessible to the [class loader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.html).